# Search hard drive for all media files of a specific bitrate?

Tags: windows-7, search, bitrate

Is it possible to search my hard drive for all MP3's of a 320 bitrate?

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Comment: This isn't an feature of `Window Search` at this time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do so trivially, because I don't think Windows 7 'knows about' file bitrates in it's meta data.

So you'll have to 'do it yourself'. I'd take the approach:

- get Perl ([ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) do one, there are others)
- Install `MP3::Info` module (`cpan install MP3::Info`). It'll ask a few questions, just accept defaults.
- Run a perl script to do it:

Something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MP3::Info;
use File::Find;

my $bitrate_target = 320;

sub print_if_bitrate {
    return unless m/\.mp3$/;    #skip any non-mp3 files.
    my $info = get_mp3info($File::Find::name);
    if ( not defined $info ) {
        print "$File::Find::name has an invalid tag\n";
        return;
    }
    my $bitrate = $info->{BITRATE};
    if ( not defined $bitrate ) {
        print "$File::Find::name - no bit rate defined\n";
        return;
    }
    if ( $bitrate >= $bitrate_target ) {
        print "($bitrate) $File::Find::name\n";
    }
}

#double slashed needed, because backslash has a special meaning.
find( \&print_if_bitrate, 'C:\\Users\\me\\MP3' );
```

(Save as 'find_mp3.pl' - activestate installer should associate with `.pl` files. )

Tested on my Windows 7 system. (Albeit with a lower bit rate, as I don't have any 320 sample files)